# C# Winform select SQL Server and database to connect to

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a small c# Winforms application with two dropdown/combo boxes, a test field and button, that will allow the user to pick the server, the database and then enter a ref id and search for the record.

I'm struggling with how to get the comboboxes to allow me to select the server and then database on the second dropdown.

I've added the three servers in the `ApplicatonSettings`, I just don't know the best way to start/do this so hoping for suggestions?

Comment: If you have multiple connection strings, wouldn't the drop-down just show the list of connection strings and then you'd use the one the user selects when building your database context?

Comment: DO you want user to select server and then in same combobox databases appear and he select it?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a custom configuration section (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) with the list of connections and use that as a data source for the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a SettingsForm(with the properties of the connection string), then have a MainForm where they can hit the dropdown combo-box. Add a SQL Data Source to your project.

Then do something similar to this to get the instances:

```
    private List<string> GetSqlInstances(bool serverDiscovery = false)
    {
        if (serverDiscovery && InstancesLoaded) { return null; }
        var serverList = new List<string>();
        InstancesLoaded = true;

        var instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        var table = instance.GetDataSources();
        if (table.Rows == null) { return null; }
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            serverList.Add(row["ServerName"].ToString());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["InstanceName"].ToString()))
                serverList.Add(row["ServerName"] + "\\" + row["InstanceName"]);
        }

        return serverList;
    }

    #region Database_Combobox

    private void cbxDatabaseName_ButtonPressed(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        cbxDatabaseName.Properties.Items.Clear();
        if (SqlHelper == null) { return; }
        try
        {
            var conStr = SqlHelper.GenerateSqlConnectionString
            (
                cbxSQLInstances?.Text,
                IntegratedSecurity,
                string.Empty,
                txtUserName?.Text,
                txtPassword?.Text
            );

            var con = conStr?.ConnectionString != null ? new SqlConnection(conStr.ConnectionString) : null;

            if (con == null)
                return;

            con.Open();
            var databases = con.GetSchema("Databases");
            if (databases?.Rows != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in databases.Rows)
                    cbxDatabaseName.Properties.Items.Add(row.Field<string>(@"database_name"));
            }
            cbxDatabaseName.ShowPopup();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```